# How to get the first 2 digits of a number

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently working the cs50 lesson cash homework and I can't get first 2 digits of the number. This is what I tried before.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    long twodigit, cardnumber;
    cardnumber = get_long("card number:\n");
    twodigit = cardnumber;
    if (twodigit >= 99) {
        do { 
            twodigit = round(twodigit / 10);
        } while (twodigit >= 99);
        if (twodigit == 34 || twodigit == 37) {
            printf("American Express");
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: When parsing credit card numbers it is generally better to operate on strings rather than integer types.

Comment: If you still need help then please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) as well as the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: @DJSchaffner I dont get it can you explain please he gets mod 10 so I dıd mod 100 but nothing happened 10 or 100

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, for some reason i thought you wanted the last 2 digits.

Comment: @kaylum how can ı do that with string in djschaffner's advice link makes string but its way too long

Comment: Since i can't edit my comment anymore here: Assuming the credit card has 16 digits you could then do `(int) ((cardnumber / pow(10, 14)) + 0.5f)` if im not mistaken

Comment: @DJSchaffner: `round(cardnumber / pow(10, 14))` is not advisable because converting `cardnumber` to `double` type produces a `double` value, that potentially has different leading digits, plus `round` is inappropriate too as `round(999 / 10)` is `100`, not `99`. Adding `0.5` is a mistake too.

Comment: @chqrlie Why is adding 0.5 a mistake?

Comment: @DJSchaffner: because you want truncation toward 0 so `999xxx` becomes `99`, whereas `(int)(9990000000000000 / pow(10, 14) + 0.5)` evaluates to `100`.

Comment: @chqrlie Oh you are totally right i missed that. Gotta be something like this then `(int) (floor(9990000000000000 / pow(10, 14)) + 0.5)`

Comment: @DJSchaffner: why insist on the `+ 0.5`? If you know the number has 16 digits, just use `(int)(cardumber / 1e14)`.

Comment: If input was `"000123"`, should the _first 2 digits of a number_ be `00` or `12`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct but:

- you should stop when the number is `99`, so the test should be `while (twodigit > 99)`
- the test should be performed **before** the division. As a rule of thumb, avoid `do`/`while` loops: this type of loop is confusing and error prone.
- you should check the number of digits too.
- there is no need for `round()`: integer division computes the integer quotient. `round()` is a floating point function.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    long twodigit, cardnumber;
    int ndigits;
    cardnumber = get_long("card number:\n");
    if (cardnumber > 9) {
        twodigit = cardnumber;
        ndigits = 2;
        while (twodigit > 99) {
            twodigit = twodigit / 10;
            ndigits += 1;
        }
        if ((twodigit == 34 || twodigit == 37) && ndigits == 13) {
            printf("American Express\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding; `cardnumber = get_long("card number:\n");
    if (cardnumber > 9) {`  a 16 digit card number is always going to be greater than 9

Comment: @user3629249: the user could enter any `long` value at the `get_long()` prompt. The code computes the number of digits correctly if `cardnumber` is positive and has at least 2 digits, hence the test. Furthermore, card numbers typically have 16 digits, but older ones had just 13.

Comment: Yes, the user could enter any 'long' value.   That is one of the reasons that the entered value should be a char array, not a long int

Comment: @user3629249: in which case the user can enter any string. I agree that strings are a better approach for this problem, but input validation is not the focus of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getFirstTwo(int number, int ignoresign)
{
    int result;
    int mask = 10;

    if((number >= 0 && number < 100) || (number < 0 && number > -100))
    {
        result = number;
    }
    else
    {
        while(abs(number / mask) > 99) mask *= 10;
        result = number / mask;
    }
    if(ignoresign) result = abs(result);
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", getFirstTwo(-345466, 0));
    printf("%d\n", getFirstTwo(-2147483648, 0));
    printf("%d\n", getFirstTwo(2147483647, 0));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/98eaje

Comment: `if((number >= 0 && number < 100) || (number < 0 && number > -100))` simplifies as `if (number > -100 && number < 100)`

Comment: Why not use: `while(abs(number) > 99) number /= 10;` ?

Comment: @chqrlie `if` is intentional to show the beginner OP the logic of it

Comment: Of course `INT_MIN` is a problem... then `while(abs(number / 10) > 9) number /= 10;`

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate the user's first 2 input digits, even if they were `'0'`, I'd go for a *string* approach.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
```

Test if input string is only numeric characters and at least 2 digits.

```
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%*[0-9]%n", &n);
  if (n >= 2 && buf[n] == '\n') {
```

Convert first two to an `int`.

```
    int leading2;
    sscanf(buf, "%2d", &leading2);
    printf("Leading 2 digits %02d\n", leading2);
```